# ZendForm: move a picture into a folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

I'm working on a project with ZF2 and Zend Form. I'd like to add an avatar into a user profile.

The problem is that I only get the file name and save it in the DB. I would like to insert it into a folder so I'll be able to get it and display it. The rest of the form is working.

My guess is that I have to get information from $FILES, but I have no idea how to do this. I've read the documentation but can't see how to apply this to my project.

Thank you in advance!

Here's my Controller Action

```
public function signinAction()
    {
        $this->em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');

        $form = new SignupForm($this->em);

        $model = new ViewModel(array("form" => $form));

        $url = $this->url()->fromRoute("signin");
        $prg = $this->prg($url, true);

        if($prg instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response){
           return $prg;
        }
        else if($prg === false){
           return $model;
        }

        $user = new User();
        $form->bind($user) ;
        $form->setData($prg) ;

        if($form->isValid()){
            $bcrypt = new Bcrypt() ;
            $pwd = $bcrypt->create($user->getPassword());
            $user->setPassword($pwd);
            $this->em->persist($user) ;
            $this->em->flush() ;

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('login');
        }

        return $model ;
    }
```

Here's my form file :

```
class SignupForm extends Form 
{
    private $em = null;

    public function __construct($em = null) {
        $this->em = $em;
        parent::__construct('frm-signup');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');
        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($this->em, 'Application\Entity\User'));

        //Other fields
         ...

        //File
        $this->add(array(
            'type' => "File",
            'name' => 'avatar',
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Avatar',
            ),     
        ));    

        //Submit
         ...         
    }   
}
```

And the form in my view :

```
        $form = $this->form;         
         echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
         //other formRow
         echo $this->formFile($form->get('avatar')); 
         echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
         echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you could look at for getting your avatar to work:

1. **Using the Gravatar view helper (uses `gravatar.com` service that automatically links images to email addresses)**

   - documentation on using the gravatar service can be found **[here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.gravatar.html)**
2. **Upload images yourself with the file upload classes that are shipped with ZF2:**

   - form class for file upload can be found **[here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html)**
   - input filter class documentation can be found **[here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.input-filter.file-input.html)**

If you follow those docs you should be able to manage what you want.

---

**Note:** check especially the use of [the `Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload` filter](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.filter.file.rename-upload.html) in the example in the input filter documentation. This filter renames/moves the uploaded avatar file to the desired location.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I finally did this yesterday but I'm hurting in a new problem (I did a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874645/zend-form-call-to-undefined-method-zend-inputfilter-inputfiltergetfilterchai ) because of the method Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter::getFilterChain(). If you have time to take a look, I would be very glad ;)